# Show a string depending on shipping country in WooCommerce checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i want to show a string in the checkout in woocommerce which depends on the shipping country. I use the following code:

```
<?php global $woocommerce; ?>

        <?php $current_cc = $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_country() ?>

    

        <?php  if ($current_cc = DE) { ?>

            <p><?php  echo var_dump($current_cc);?></p>

         <tr class="order-total">
            <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?><br><small 
 class="shopping_cart_total_vat_message">inkl. MwSt.</small></th>
            <td><?php wc_cart_totals_order_total_html(); ?></td>
         </tr>

         <?php } else { ?>

             <tr class="order-total">
             <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?><br><small 
  class="shopping_cart_total_vat_message">exkl. MwSt.</small></th>
            <td><?php wc_cart_totals_order_total_html(); ?></td>
        </tr>

            <?php } ?>

         <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total' ); ?>
```

The var_dump always shows DE also when i choose another country. Where is the problem?

i hope somebody can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side language. If the page is not reloaded, the content processed by PHP will not be displayed.

You can get what you want by **using a JQuery script**.

The following code will only be shown on the checkout page and will display custom text after the shipping country paragraph.

```
// adds custom text based on shipping country value in checkout
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_custom_text_based_on_shipping_country' );
function add_custom_text_based_on_shipping_country() {
    // only in the checkout
    if ( ! is_checkout() ) {
        return;
    }
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // show custom text on page load (based on shipping country value)
            jQuery('<div id="custom_string"><span>'+jQuery("#shipping_country").find("option:selected").val()+'</span></div>').insertAfter('#shipping_country_field');
            // replaces the text of the #custom_string element based on the value of the selected shipping country
            jQuery('#shipping_country').change(function() {
                var shippingCountry = jQuery(this).find('option:selected').val();
                var customContent = '';
                switch ( shippingCountry ) {
                    case 'FR':
                        customContent = '<span>'+shippingCountry+'</span>';
                        break;
                    case 'DE':
                        customContent = '<span>'+shippingCountry+'</span>';
                        break;
                    case 'IT':
                        customContent = '<span>'+shippingCountry+'</span>';
                        break;
                    default:
                        customContent = '';
                        break;
                }
                jQuery('#custom_string').html(customContent);
            });
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*